# change slides automatics by time javascript

Tags: javascript

i created this slide show but it does not change by it self how can i set a time for it to change automatically is there is a way to that now it will just change whenever i press a button otherwise it wont change  here is my codes

> HTML

```
    <div class="slideshow-container" style="width: 100%;height: 500px" >

 <?php 
    $get = $data->show(" SELECT * FROM movies LIMIT 3 ");
foreach ($get as $row) {
 $id=$row['id'];
 $name=$row['m_name'];
 $type=$row['type'];
 $description=$row['description'];
 $trailer=$row['trailer'];
 $background=$row['background'];
     ?>
  <div class="mySlides " style="">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $background; ?>" style="width:100%;height: 500px">
    <div class="content text-left">

    <h2 style="color: white;"><?php echo "$name"; ?><a><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger p-1 m-2"><span class="fa fa-play">ترایله‌ر</button></span></h2>


    <h3 style="color: #fdd835;"><?php echo "$type"; ?></h3>
    <h3 style="color: #fdd835;"><?php echo "$description"; ?></h3>

  </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center;width: 100%">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
 var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

im trying to that for about 2 days and i still did not get it can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If you need to animate the slides continuously after a period, then use the `setInterval` method.

The following will animate your slides after 3 s. But please make sure your `slideIndex` is initialized.

```
   var intervalID = setInterval(()=> {
          try {
             showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
          } catch Exception {
            console.log(Exception);
          }
        }, 3000);
```

If you want to remove the above interval worker, you will need to use the following

```
   clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: when i put anything like that the whole images are gone the slide index sure have it is own value that is working and it is inside the same function

Comment: i put it in it now i got images but it wont change after 3 seconds just like before

Comment: no it showed no image like again  i didnt get any errors this time

Comment: i dont know if this related to that or not but here is 1 error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: I think this is an issue. Can you check what is the unexpected identifier? Is it the ````=>````?

Comment: Also, can you explain more on "it won't change after 3 seconds just like before"? Does the previous answer without the try-catch block worked for you?

Comment: it does says where is the error when i removed the > it said it is on ` ')'`   i meant the slieds wont go to another one it is stopped in both it is same result